# como llamar a funciones de JS antes que carge la pagina

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

estoy desarrollando una web sucede que tengo un menu horizontal con un `position : fixed`, con una funcion de JS que detecta el scroll  le cambio el color del background  al menu para que se pueda ver de forma legible , ya que por defecto el fondo es transparente pero en algunas paginas necesito que se inice con fondo blanco eso lo hago con la misma  funcion que evalua el scroll pero mi problema es que demora mucho en ejecutar la funcion como la pongo en `<body onload="calculaAlto()">` y la pagina demora como 2 segundos en cargar , entonces el color de fondo cambia  despues de 2 segundos los cual se ve muy mal. alguien sabe de algún evento de html o js que me sirva para que esa funcion se ejecute de manera asíncrona al resto del DOM ? . GRACIAS DE ANTE  MANO aqui les dejo una parte del codigo.

```
function calculaAlto(bloque){
    var box = document.getElementById(bloque);
    var altoBox = box.scrollHeight;
    var menu = document.getElementById('menuh');
    var itemsMen = document.getElementsByClassName('titulosItemsMenu');
    var  logo = document.getElementById('logoimg');
    var subMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('subMenu-li');
        if(document.documentElement.scrollTop>=altoBox || document.body.scrollTop >= altoBox){
            menu.style.backgroundColor ="white";
            logo.src ="img/logo-praco-blue.png";
            subMenu[0].style.backgroundColor ="white";
            subMenu[1].style.backgroundColor ="white";
            menu.style.boxShadow = " 0px 2px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
                itemsMen[0].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[1].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[2].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[3].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[4].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[5].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[6].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
                itemsMen[7].style.color ="#0E4B8E";
        }else{
                menu.style.backgroundColor ="transparent";
                logo.src ="img/logo-praco-monochrome-white.png";
                subMenu[0].style.backgroundColor ="transparent";
                subMenu[1].style.backgroundColor ="transparent";
                menu.style.boxShadow = " 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
                    itemsMen[0].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[1].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[3].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[4].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[5].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[6].style.color ="white";
                    itemsMen[7].style.color ="white";            
        }
}
```

con esa funcion le cambio el color de fondo al menu y algunas otras cosas

```
<html>
 <body onload="calculaAlto(n)">
<div id="menu"> contenido del menu(con position fixed) </div>
<div id="n"> mide 0px </div>
<div > mide 100px </div>
<div > mide 100px </div>
</body>
</html>
```

solo es un ejemplo del HTML  ya que el real es muchismo mas grande pero espero que se pueda entender mi problema.
por defecto en este caso el menu se deberia iniciar con fondo blanco y si lo hace pero demora mucho

Comment: Los elementos que manipulas dentro de la funcion necesitan ser cargados al DOM antes de que puedas trabajar con ellos, por lo tanto, no es posible ejecutar la funcion antes de que el cuerpo carge.

Comment: si del lado del servidor tenes apache y php podés jugar con los buffers para ejecutar algún javascript mientras sigue cargando la página -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152441/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes encararlo de varias maneras aquí una opción:

Un "cargando" con spinner CSS de [loading.io](https://loading.io/css/) tapa todo hasta que termine de cargar la página, hacés tus cálculos y por último desactivas el "cargando".

El `z-index: 99999;` es para que quede por sobre tu menú fixed.

```js
function hacemoAlguna() {
  // simulamos tiempo de carga
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('cargando').style.display = 'none';
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#cargando {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.lds-dual-ring {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  margin-top: -32px;
}

.lds-dual-ring:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-color: #fff transparent #fff transparent;
  animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes lds-dual-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="hacemoAlguna()">
  <div id="cargando">
    <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam rhoncus finibus diam, ac vulputate orci interdum ac. Vestibulum ac fringilla libero, sit amet fringilla mi. Aenean eu tellus justo. Aenean tempus elit in nunc viverra vestibulum. Duis nisi
    sem, tristique vitae urna in, sagittis fermentum mauris. Nunc in sodales diam, nec dictum urna. Curabitur eget eleifend ligula, eu ultrices lacus. Vestibulum fermentum libero a congue finibus. Pellentesque et sagittis nulla. In a vestibulum tellus.
    Donec ac eros nisl. Cras ut nunc vitae arcu lacinia semper et at odio. Nam eget volutpat diam, eu gravida libero. Sed sit amet mauris massa. Fusce turpis odio, congue pellentesque augue ut, lacinia tempor purus. Nullam viverra velit dolor, a tincidunt
    nulla mattis eget. Proin dapibus nisl nec auctor gravida. Etiam ut pharetra eros. Integer a dolor vitae felis aliquam dictum. Nulla interdum, nisl non interdum dictum, nibh erat porttitor ante, at hendrerit eros ligula ac dui. Praesent sodales nunc
    nibh, non convallis arcu aliquam ut. Mauris placerat auctor vestibulum. Curabitur augue diam, commodo at ipsum vitae, aliquam rhoncus mauris. Vestibulum at metus in ipsum mattis volutpat pulvinar vel magna. Nullam tincidunt rutrum mi. Proin eu libero
    ut eros eleifend dapibus non ac turpis. Pellentesque pretium ante a feugiat feugiat. Maecenas sed ultrices quam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus mattis luctus ex eget gravida. Vivamus condimentum ultricies sollicitudin. Ut tempus massa sed neque
    fermentum porta. Aliquam maximus at nisl ac varius. Nunc in urna pulvinar, finibus lectus a, ullamcorper magna. Nullam massa purus, vestibulum laoreet sem ac, volutpat rutrum urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
    per inceptos himenaeos. Integer bibendum consectetur elementum. Ut consequat lectus non ante vehicula venenatis. Sed vel nulla lacus. Ut dapibus diam velit, eget faucibus mauris commodo nec. Mauris blandit enim orci. Aenean at mi sagittis, placerat
    arcu aliquet, egestas velit. Nullam at diam eleifend, viverra purus nec, condimentum erat. Vestibulum placerat tristique leo eu ullamcorper. Integer placerat luctus augue, id convallis tellus varius non. Praesent aliquet ligula bibendum ante aliquet,
    et egestas dui egestas. Donec tellus mi, vulputate eu nunc at, cursus maximus sapien. Nam condimentum enim eu consequat euismod. Praesent id consectetur augue, a maximus risus. Nam euismod ligula non dui tincidunt suscipit. Aliquam ut nisl eget tortor
    consequat ultrices eu a nisl. Aliquam sed nulla quis arcu convallis cursus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean efficitur finibus nisi, ac faucibus risus vehicula at. Curabitur vulputate
    lectus velit, a pharetra nisi vehicula sed. Nam ultrices lobortis nisl, at condimentum lorem viverra vel. Cras metus nisl, scelerisque blandit odio tristique, commodo tristique enim. Ut dictum odio tellus, quis sagittis nulla congue id. Integer viverra
    tortor in pharetra laoreet. Etiam vel neque lectus. Donec suscipit fringilla quam quis porttitor. Fusce hendrerit quam nec justo dignissim accumsan. Mauris sollicitudin vehicula nisi a placerat.
  </div>
</body>
```

Otra opción es meter un tag `<script>` justo luego de que cargan las cosas que necesitas para calcular el alto, el script se ejecuta con lo que se cargó hasta ese momento y luego continúa la carga, pero sin saber cómo es ni de qué depende es difícil proponer algo.

Comment: Gracias  , no me esperaba una solución asi pero almenos  sirve .